# Show gradle files as part of their modules in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle

By default Android Studio shows all build.gradle files in a neat list at the very bottom below all modules. This becomes problematic in projects with over 100 modules as its hard to scan through them all to find the one youre looking for.

Is it possible to instead show them as part of the module they belong to? Right next to the files containing any code in the module!